Azure Service Bus - Differentiating between Messages on the same Topic
I'm relatively new to Azure Service Bus (and message queueing in general), and have run into technical detail that seemed like a simple question but without a solution clearly available online.
The C# project I'm working within leverages Azure Service Bus, which it has previously only used to receive some details from a third party and update an existing entity. The flow of that looks like this:

In the Inbound project, a C# HttpTrigger receives a POST request from the third party

The received payload is deserialized into the required format (an internal DTO)
DTO is placed on the service bus under the topic (let's call it Items for the sake of simplicity)


In the main BackEnd project, a C# ServiceBusTrigger is subscribed to the Items topic and receives the message
-  Deserializes the message
-  Uses the data to update the relevant entry in the database

This has worked fine for as long as it has been implemented. But it is now at a point where the use cases have expanded to include the third party sending data to create a new Item entry, not just edit an existing one.
This will mean a new endpoint in the Inbound project, receiving a different (larger) payload an deserializing it to a different DTO, but ideally placing it on the same topic as it will still fall under Items in terms of domain.
What I am now trying to work out is how to elegantly receive these two different types of messages from the same topic and have them correctly handled.
Essentially will it be possible to have two ServiceBusTrigger classes receiving the payloads and have one handle the updates and one the creations as required? Do I need to add something into the payload to differentiate the type of operation? etc
Here is the code I have so far:
//in Inbound proj

public class PostItemUpdateHttpTrigger(IEventBusService eventBusService)
{
    public const string FunctionRoute = "ItemUpdate";

    [Function(FunctionRoute)]
    [OpenApiOperation(operationId: FunctionRoute, tags: ["Items"])]
    [OpenApiRequestBody(nameof(ItemUpdateDto), typeof(ItemUpdateDto))]
    [OpenApiResponseWithoutBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, Description = "Publishes the received data, to update an existing item, to the 'items' service bus topic.")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = FunctionRoute)] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        var appointmentUpdateDto = await req.ReadFromJsonAsync<ItemUpdateDto>()
            ?? throw new Exception("Error deserialising data.");

        await eventBusService.SendAsync(appointmentUpdateDto, Topics.Items);

        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}

// In BackEnd proj

public class ItemServiceBusTrigger(IMediator mediator)
{
    [Function(nameof(ItemServiceBusTrigger))]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(
        "Items",
        "%ServiceBusSettings:SubscriptionName%",
        Connection = "ServiceBusSettings:ConnectionString")] string inputEvent)
    {
        var scanningResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemUpdateDto>(inputEvent);
        var command = UpdateCommand.FromItemUpdateDto(scanningResult!);
        await mediator.Send(command);
    }
}


Any advice on how to implement this additional use case cleanly is greatly appreciated, mainly with a focus on not over-engineering with something like a whole new topic etc.
Thanks,
Mark

There are two options I can think of for this scenario.

Subscription/Function per message type
Single subscription/Function for all messages

Regardless of the method you choose, you'll need to stamp your messages with an identifier to identify the message type of the payload.
Subscription/Function per message type
Having a dedicated subscription and a function for each message type. In your scenario, that would be one for Items and another for Item message types.
Pros:

Simple relationship of a subscription per message type
Simple subscription filter for a specific message type that could be achieved with a correlation filter for performance sake

Cons:

Whenever the number of message types to be handled increases, additional subscriptions and functions will be required.

Single subscription/Function for all messages
A single subscription with a catch-all filter delivers all messages to the same Service Bus-triggered function. The function then looks at the message type, usually expressed via either a system or user property (header), and invokes the appropriate handler.
Pros:

Single subscription that doesn't change over time if additional message types are added
Easy to test the logic responsible for message dispatching for handling

Cons:

Whenever the number of message types to be handled increases, additional, though minor, logic to handle a new message type must be added to the trigger function.
Message should be received as ServiceBusReceived message to access the properties*

* while not really a con, I decided to list it there as it does deviate from how you receive your payloads today, as string.

Thanks for your help on this. I will have a play around with both approaches and see what suits best. Appreciate you!
